# Which kind of bicycles is better and comfortable for shorter communtes, 4-5 km daily

Tags: road-bike, commuter, health, ergonomics

This kind straight handles

[image]

or this kind?

[image]

Comment: The best kind _for you_ is whichever kind is most comfortable _for you_.

Comment: I am tall, and I find that flat bars work better for me.  The swept-back styles tend to interfere with my knees when turning.

Answer (score 3):

My priorities:

1. Right size for you. A **must**.
2. Light weight as possible/desired
3. Low price - it needs to be do a simple job without being a thief magnet (at least here)

Answer (score 2):

The difference between handlebars, or in general body postures on bicycle, starts to show itself at distances of 50 km. For 5 kilometers a day, which I assume consist of two intervals of 2.5 km each (to work and back), it really does not matter. I would say gearing would play more difference than type of bike.

Comment: My route if flat and 2 traffic signals. Does gearing help in such shorter distance?

Comment: If it is flat, then gearing generally does not matter either. Consider that you might want to use your bike to travel to some other places. Thus you need to consider your environment in general — does it tend to be hilly or there is not a single prick for dozens of miles around?

Comment: I don't go to mountains on/with bicycle. There is a probability though that if I move to a city which could have uneven surface. I think bicycle with gears needs more and costlier maintainence tha non-geared one.

Comment: Single speed bicycles do indeed have less parts to service, so yes, theoretically they would cost less to maintain. In practice it depends more on how, how often and in which conditions a bicycle is ridden.

Comment: As Grigory mentioned. Over all not a big difference in maintenance cost if riding accurate and spending some time per month to clean and lubricate.

Answer (score 2):

One style of flat handlebar is not absolutely better than another. You should test ride some bikes and see what you personally prefer.

Bicycle stores offer test rides in the USA, but I realize it might not be the case where you live.